# whats a good cross platform developer tools to use

Tags: cross-platform

currently looking to make my own web app with mobile stuff , but i am currently in a pickle , i am in a dilemma as to what stack to use for my app ,what are the other options to choose from in making a cross platform app , other than what visual studio is offering , because in my head i should just do a basic ruby rails for backend and have a nice android studio java for the application. but it will eat a bit of time to make .

so i am currently leaning on a nice cross-platform  dev tool that i can use to make my whole app , do you guys have any other recommendations other than what i said , or for me to just man up and git gud to make it all happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any from these mentioned once. I have wrote them in order.

1. Xamarin
2. PhoneGap
3. Ionic

These are the best tools available, anyway you can find more.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: You can add `React Native` to that list